# "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" after applying server updates

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

We are hosting an ASP.NET Webforms site with version 4.0 of the .NET framework.

We started getting the following error after applying server patches to our .NET site last week:

> "System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC
>   failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure
>   that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

Only a small percentage of our site visitors are getting this error.  We can't reproduce it ourselves.  Over half of the errors are being generated by mobile devices (which is suspicious as mobile devices account for just a small a minority of our visitors).  We are hosting on a single Windows 2008R2 server.  The error is being generated by many different .NET pages so it isn't limited to any one page.

Even though we aren't on a server farm we added a static machineKey entry to our web.config file but it didn't make a difference.

As stated, this problem began immediately after we applied several Windows updates to the server last week.  Any ideas?

Here's a list of the updates we applied:

[{7CA28304-D86F-4ACA-97FA-D126E0D02416}](http://www.advanceduninstaller.com/Update-for-Microsoft-Office-2010-KB2553347-32-Bit-Edition-8cbb7a1f43a6165ab558c6579ea61cba-application.htm)

{E5FD83F7-AD96-4105-94BE-27947D5D638F}

[{DC65D0CA-893D-4BFE-8FE9-DF4ED90652DB}](http://www.advanceduninstaller.com/Microsoft-Office-Professional-Plus-2010-e98222998a22d9c0f992d840ab30ced4-application.htm)

[KB3081320](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3081320)

[KB3092601](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3092601)

[KB3097988](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3097988)

[KB3101722](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3101722)

[KB3108371](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3108371)

[KB3108381](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3108381)

[KB3108664](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3108664)

[KB3109094](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3109094)

[KB3109103](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3109103)

[KB3109560](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3109560)

[KB3110329](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3110329)

[KB3118401](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3118401)

[KB3122646](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3122646)

[KB3126041](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3126041)

[KB3126587](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3126587)

[KB3127219](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3127219)

[KB3133043](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3133043)

[KB3135982](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3135982)

[KB3139398](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3139398)

[KB3139914](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3139914)

[KB3139921](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3139921)

[KB3139940](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3139940)

[KB3140709](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3140709)

[KB3141083](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3141083)

[KB3142023](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3142023)

[KB3142041](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3142041)

[KB3145739](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3145739)

[KB3146706](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3146706)

[KB3146963](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3146963)

[KB3147071](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3147071)

[KB3149090](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3149090)

[KB3153171](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3153171)

[KB3156016](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3156016)

[KB3156017](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3156017)

[KB3156019](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3156019)

[KB3159398](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3159398)

[KB3161561](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3161561)

[KB3161949](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3161949)

[KB3163244](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3163244)

[KB3164033](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3164033)

[KB3164035](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3164035)

[KB3167679](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3167679)

[KB3170455](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3170455)

[KB3175443](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3175443)

[KB3177723](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3177723)

[KB3177725](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3177725)

[KB3178034](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3178034)

[KB3099869](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3099869)

[KB3097996](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3097996)

[KB2901983](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2901983)

[KB3098781](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=3098781)

Comment: Are you seeing any app pool recycle events in the system event log?

Comment: No.  But even if the app pool was recycling the fact that we've added a static machineKey entry to our web.config file should eliminate that as a cause.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218)?

Comment: Yes.  As stated, we are not operating on multiple servers and are not using an auto-generated machineKey.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was not due to a Windows patch after all.  We'd seen this behavior after restarting the server in the past but nowhere near this scale.  We've surmised that this was the first server reboot we've done during a VERY busy time of the year for our user base.

It appears that this error is a result of a user being signed into our site and then leaving the browser un-used (with the site tab open) between server reboots.  Most of the users that got this error were on mobile devices - which typically don't actually shut down the browser app between uses).